# TCP congestion control-fast retransmit and fast recovery

Tags: networking, tcp, congestion-control

QUESTION

Suppose you are using TCP to transfer a 4 MB file over a network. The receiver advertises a receive window of 4 MB. Assume that the retransmission timers expire after 5 RTTs.

(a) If TCP sends 4KB segments, how many RTTs does it take to send the file, assuming that there are no segment losses?

(b) Describe what happens if the first segment sent after the send window reaches 1MB is lost. Assume that the version of TCP you are using does not implement fast retransmit and fast recovery. How many RTTs does it take to send the file?

(c) Now assume that the version of TCP you are using implements fast retransmit and fast recovery. How many RTTs are saved by the fact that your TCP implements fast retransmit and fast recovery?

I have recently started studying Congestion control but I am little confused with how fast retransmit/recovery works differently from ordinary retransmission. Please explain about that.